# Separate into different files after splitting the pattern

Tags: unix

I have following pattern

```
k0
lj33
lp90
ko00
j9
mn12
sh30
lp33
ji90
e3
nd32
jk90
hi43
df45
cv89
er43
```

I need different files containing

```
File1   File2   File3
k0        j9    e3
lj33    mn12    nd32
lp90    sh30    jk90
ko00    lp33    hi43
        ji90    df45
                cv89
                er43
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you mean: each file starts with a two-character string?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean: each file starts with a two-character string?

Try this command:

```
csplit input /^..$/ {*}
```

Please ignore the first empty file `xx00`.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you need the data to be split when you reach a two character string:

```
awk '{if(length($0)==2){filename=$0}; print >filename}' your_file
```